# Kivy: How can I refresh the text and progressbar of a counter?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy-language, kivymd

Im trying to make a counter app that starts counting to 5 after a button is pressed. It shows the first number and updates the progress bar. It then pauses for 2 seconds before showing the next number and incrementing the progress bar and count shown on the screen.

The problem is that the app just freezes and then jumps immediately to the end without showing any of the progress in between.

This is my code below. Ive searched all of stackoverflow and I cant seem to find the answer. I've tried Clock.schedule_interval and also threads but neither seem to work.

Any ideas?

'''

```
class MyDemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.screen = Screen()
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        run_button = MDRectangleFlatIconButton(
            text='Run',
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.4},
            on_release=self.run_countdown,
            icon="play"
        )
        self.progress = MDProgressBar(
            value=0,
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2},
            width=600,
            size_hint_x=None
        )
        self.info = MDLabel(
            text='',
            halign="center",
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.7},
            font_style='H5',
            theme_text_color="Custom"
        )
        topbar = MDToolbar(
            title="My First App",
            md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
            type="top"
        )
        topbar_label = MDLabel(
            text="",
        )
        box_layout = MDBoxLayout(
            orientation="vertical"
        )
        box_layout.add_widget(topbar)
        box_layout.add_widget(topbar_label)
        self.screen.add_widget(box_layout)
        self.screen.add_widget(run_button)
        self.screen.add_widget(self.progress)
        self.screen.add_widget(self.info)
        return self.screen

    def run_countdown(self, obj):
        stop = 5
        self.progress.max = stop
        for i in range(stop):
            self.progress.value = i+1
            self.info.text = str(i+1)
            sleep(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    MyDemoApp().run()
```

'''